# How to avoid triggering unique validator on model edition?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask, SQLAlchemy and WTForms. I have a number of properties in my model object which are marked as `unique` and `nullable=False`. This works fine when creating a new row in the database but when I try to edit an existing object the validator on WTForms fails with

`{'aproperty': [u'Already exists.']}`

How can I make this validation pass without having to change my data model?

**Update**

Following the [documentation](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html#using-unique-validator-with-existing-objects) was of no use to me.

Comment: How are you instantiating the form?

Comment: form = MyForm(request.form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate the existing record with the form. Otherwise the validator has no way of knowing that you're updating an existing record instead of creating a new one. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
current_obj = ...
form = MyForm(request.form, obj=current_obj)
form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(current_obj)
```